# Does the Raspberry Pi run hot?

Tags: linux, cooling, raspberry-pi

I know they come out with a plugin computer called the Guru Plug a while back in which someone complained it ran so hot they burned their fingers while trying to unplug an ethernet cable: http://1wt.eu/articles/guruplug-slow-heater

And I was wondering if anybody knew if the Raspberry Pi suffered from similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Raspberry Pi Forums](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BK5D0GehtK0J:www.raspberrypi.org/forum/general-discussion/rasppi-heat-output%20raspberry%20pi%20heat&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) (Google cache as the site is overloaded at the moment):

> The alpha board SoC gets warm to the touch – not too hot to touch, I"d guess at about 45-50C. If you are really hammering the GPU it might get a bit hotter.

Answer (score 1):

Me and a friend of mine have been playing with Raspberry Pi's for the past few weeks. My friend noticed that while playing 1080p video the Pi would get very hot. He was having trouble with xbmc freezing after playing a video. We used some VGA RAM heatsinks and now his Pi can play several 1080p videos without any system hangs or lockups.